# Invalid viewstate - Windows SharePoint Services 3.0

Tags: search, wss-3.0

All users in a department have issues searching the Knowledge Base and I'm on a different SharePoint site and I see similar issues.

Error they get is as follows and I see something similar with farm or system account:

> Invalid viewstate.
>   Client IP: 10.242.128.16
>   Port: 61529
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
>   ViewState: 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
>   Referer: `http://xxxx.internal/department/GroupIT/teams/ServiceDesk/default.aspx`
>   Path: /_layouts/searchresults.aspx
>   Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint

We’re told this was working on Friday.

I came across this:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263527(office.12).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263527%28office.12%29.aspx)

I don't see an option in Office SharePoint Server Shared Services (in step 3).

Any other suggestions?

Comment: look at the ULS logs if you get any detailed error while performing this steps.  Also look at the event logs for your servers

Comment: @SudhirKesharwani The last logs in c$\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS are PSCDiagnostics and last updates are 13th. Event viewer has no updated logs after error. Is there a query I could do on the database similar to this?